# Sell Unused domains?

Tags: domains

I am streamlining my domains under one domain so getting rid of some. I have some about 5 years old domains with stable traffic. What should I do with such domains? Where can I sell them?

I found an article [here](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_sell_my_unused_domain_names.html) but I am unsure of its quality. It suggested [GreatDomains](http://www.greatdomains.com/) -website and [Afternic](http://www.afternic.com/) -website. I would also appreciate it how you usually determine the valuation of a domain.

Comment: What are these domains? I might be interested in buying them.

Answer (score 0):

[flippa.com](http://flippa.com) is a  site for selling entire sites, but I'm sure you can sell domains only (fee for listing)